# Motor controller for two Hitec D845WP servos

Tags: microcontroller, servomotor

I am undertaking a project using two Hitec D845WP servos running at 8.4 V.

Hitec's website lists idle current of 30 mA, no load operating of 1600 mA, stall current of 10 A and motor type as "5 Poles Cored Metal Brush". I believe that I can use a Cytron 10A 5-30V Dual Channel DC Motor Driver (RB-Cyt-153).

- Can anyone please clarify the difference between a "DC Motor Driver", a "Brushed DC Motor Controller" and a "RC Servo Motor Controller"?
- Are there other components necessary in my circuit if I opt for a "Driver" compared to a "Controller" and, if so, what are they please?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Dale, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

As you know microcontroller board (e.g. arduino) have limited current output and mostly fived voltages  3.3V/5V. So they can not be used directly to power the motor, so you need either a motor driver or controller to power it.

The difference is that a motor driver only handles power, and the control has to be done by a microcontroller, often the signal to be sent to the motor driver require proper timing and care. Whereas a motor controller is a motor driver plus some logical part taking care of the low-level control of the motor, that means that you can send high-level commands to the controller like pwm or set points, and it takes care of the interaction with the driver.

Back to the driver, DC motor do not require a specific protocol to be controlled, but servos, stepper and brushless require a specific type of signal to be operated properly. 
When you buy some packaged servo, they usually consist of a DC motor and a controller, so you need to provide a high-level (eg pwm) and the required power. In that case you only need an adequate power supply and something able to produce a pwm signal.
See for example this [tutorial from howtomechatronics.com](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/how-servo-motors-work-how-to-control-servos-using-arduino/)